# Cannot create Q# Quantum Application in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019, quantum-computing, q#

I'm going to create Q# application for the first time. I installed the "Microsoft Quantum Development Kit" and I have .not core 3.1.301 (the latest)
I use VS 2019 Community Edition.

In VS, I see the Q# Application when creating new solution but when I try to create , I get below error:

> The project file cannot be opened by the project system, because it is
>   missing some critical imports or the referenced SDK cannot be found.
>
> Detailed Information: The SDK resolver "NuGetSdkResolver" failed to
>   run. Unable to find fallback package folder
>   'C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\'.
>
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\Sdks\Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk\Sdk not
>   found. Check that a recent enough .NET Core SDK is installed and/or
>   increase the version specified in global.json.

[image]

I could not find any solution over the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quantum.SDK is not distributed with the extension, instead is downloaded the first time you try to build/create the Q# application.
Looks like Visual Studio is having problems downloading it using NuGet. I can think of two reasons:
 1. You are not connected to the internet, so it can't connect to nuget.org to download the package
 2. The error points to a missing "C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\", I would suggest creating this folder.

Comment: Interesting. It worked after I created the folder. however it does not store any file there. Thanks for the hint.